# Incrementing Div Height

Tags: javascript

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="outer"> 
<div id="inner" >Inner1
    <div id="ininner1" >Ininner1</div>
    <div id="ininner2">Ininner2</div>
</div>
<div id="inner2">Inner2</div>
</div>
```

How can I increment their heights so that they are in a single column? I was thinking maybe a for loop, but I'm not quite sure how that would work with divs

```
#inner{
background-color:#B0C2F7;
top: 80px;
left: 125px;
}

#inner2{
background-color:#FF0000;
top: 180px;
left: 25px;
}
```

The Ininner divs are the same way with different numbers for 'top'. I just a way to do with a loop if possible.

Comment: @downvoter, please provide a comment at least.

Comment: a single column? Do you mean you need one div next to the other instead of below?

Comment: in css : `div {width:100%; float:left;}`

Comment: Why do you need to increment heights to get them in a single column? They do that by default: http://jsfiddle.net/297my/5/

Comment: what that should look? have you any css for that? have you an image of what are you currently viewing?

Comment: Just like a stack of boxes, I'll add the css I have to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("circle");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for(var i=0; i<innerDiv.length;i++){
    //height increment here
};
```